# Complete and Submit form in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, radio-button, urllib2, urllib

I am trying to create a python script that complets th form on this page http://segas.gr/index.php/el/2015-best-athlete by selecting the radio button with label "Γιώργος Μηλιαράς (ΣΑΚΑ) 800 μ./1,500 μ./3,000 μ" aka id="male_kids_3".

Here is my code:

```
import urllib
import urllib2

import webbrowser

url = "http://segas.gr/index.php/el/2015-best-athlete"
data = urllib.urlencode({'male_kids_3': 'checked'})
results = urllib2.urlopen(url, data)
with open("results.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(results.read())

webbrowser.open("results.html")
```

Comment: So what is the question? I don't get it.

Comment: My code doesn't work

Comment: So we are wizards that compile your code JIT for you by watching it?

Give us more information about the error itself.

Comment: Oh snap I forgot the error message

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using  selinium

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


def malakia():


    #Get url
    browser.get("http://segas.gr/index.php/el/2015-best-athlete")


    miliaras = browser.find_element_by_id("male_kids_3")
    miliaras.click()

    validate = browser.find_element_by_name("input_submit_4")
    validate.click()



if __name__ == "__main__": #Because we are bad-ass and we know python

    #Let's make sme magiKKK
    times = int(input("Πόσες φορές θέλεις να ψηφίσεις τον G #babas ??\n"))

    #create brwoser object
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()

    for i in range(times):
        malakia()
```